# codeigniter datatable send variable to datatable query

Tags: php, javascript, json, codeigniter, datatable

i used library datatable and codeigniter

i have a variable in view

```
$afd = "1"
```

and in this view i have a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatables').dataTable( {
"bJQueryUI":true,

"bProcessing": true,

"bServerSide": true,

"sPaginationType":"full_numbers",

"sAjaxSource": "<?=base_url()?>index.php/report/report/ajax_view_panen/",

"aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]

});

});  </script>
```

to call datatables in controller codeigniter . the function controller is "ajax_view_panen"

this is my controller

```
function ajax_view_panen()
{
$this->load->library('Datatables');
$this->datatables->from('panen');
$this->datatables->select('id,jml_panen,hariff_blok_id,hariff_afdeling_id,tgl_panen,bulan');
$this->datatables->where('id', $afd);
echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

the question is how to send variable `$afd` to my controller. so the variable is inside query `$this->datatables->where('id', $afd);` so the datatables show `id = 1`

sory for my bad english.

BR

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simpliest way is to send over CI function parameter

```
function ajax_view_panen($afd)
{
  ...
  $this->datatables->where('id', $afd);
  echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

so you need to pass this variable into your view and call correct url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
...
"sAjaxSource": "<?=base_url()?>index.php/report/report/ajax_view_panen/<?=$afd?>",
...
</script>
```

Note you might need to sanitize your input to be secured.

Something like `$afd = intval($afd)` if thats a numeric parameter.

Comment: you save my time. thanks it works. my fault is in javascript `"sAjaxSource": "<?=base_url()?>index.php/report/report/ajax_view_panen/"+afd",` and i use in javascript `var afd = <?php Print($afd); ?>` to get a variable. the datatable not show. by the way thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Serg is correct You can add the value to the GET variable list.

Otherwise if want to add to the post:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatables').dataTable( {
"bJQueryUI":true,
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
"sAjaxSource": "<?=base_url()?>index.php/report/report/ajax_view_panen/",
"aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        aoData.push( { "afd": "<? php echo $afd; ?>"} );
 }

});

});
```